# Jquery slideshow code from sitepoint book, error with rotatePics function

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out what is wrong (line in question has multiple asterisks)
It's a slideshow.
In the JS section, DW keeps telling me I have an error on the line that contains the rotatePics function.

Here's the HTML portion:

```
<div id=photos>

<img src="../imgs/dr_gonzalez.jpg" class=show alt="Dr. G">

<img src="../imgs/immunization.jpg" alt="SHOTZ!">

<img src="../imgs/senior_pet.jpg" alt="Former Puppies">

<img src="../imgs/vet_barnes.jpg" alt="Best doctor ever">

</div>
```

The CSS portion:

```
#photos img {position:absolute;

}



 #photos{

 width: 241px;

 height: 329px;

 overflow:hidden;

}
```

aaaaannnnnnddd the JS which is the one I need debugged:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

slideShow();

});



function slideShow() {

  var current = $('#photos .show');

  var next = current.next().length ? current.next() :

  current.siblings().first;



  current.hide().removeClass('show');

  next.fadeIn().addClass('show');



  setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);

 }



$(document).ready(function() {

rotatePics(1);

}



***function rotatePics(currentPhoto){***         

 var numberOfPhotos = $('#photos img').length;
 currentPhoto = currentPhoto % numberOfPhotos;
 $('#photos img').eq(currentPhoto).fadeOut(function (){

    $('#photos img').each(function (i)

    {

        $(this).css('zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) +currentPhoto)            numberOfPhotos);

    });



    $(this).show();



    setTimeout(function ()

    {

        rotatePics(++currentPhoto);

    }, 4000);

    });

};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Its tough to get in the swing of things, and learn to write good questions, but it gets easier.  Take the time to get your formatting down, clean up your code, perhaps create a jsfiddle, and you'll be amazed how much help the community here is willing to give.  Oh, and don't forget to upvote and/or "check" an answer that helps you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears your not using a debugger tool to help catch your simple errors. It's best to look at the browsers console and pay attention to what it says, which can direct you to errors as they happen.

Even jsFiddle has jsLint Tool to alert you for errors too!

Here is your jQuery markup that validates, but remember this is no guarantee that you have coded your script as you intended.

```js
function slideShow() {

    var current = $('#photos .show');

    var next = current.next().length ? current.next() :

    current.siblings().first;

    current.hide().removeClass('show');

    next.fadeIn().addClass('show');

    setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);

}

function rotatePics(currentPhoto) {

    var numberOfPhotos = $('#photos img').length;
    currentPhoto = currentPhoto % numberOfPhotos;
    $('#photos img').eq(currentPhoto).fadeOut(function() {

        $('#photos img').each(function(i) {
            $(this).css('zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) + currentPhoto));
        });

        $(this).show();

        setTimeout(function() {
            rotatePics(++currentPhoto);
        }, 4000);
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    slideShow();
    rotatePics(1);
});
```

Note that you should specify your functions before you call them in jQuery document ready, and although you can use two of those ready functions, you don't need it in your case.

Now that your jQuery code is bug free, you need to work out the bugs that cause the slideshow not to function as you've intended to.

***Reference:*** [**jsFiddle Beta Slideshow**](http://jsfiddle.net/WfqR9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

why make things so complicated?  You have two timer functions, and you're manipulating zindexs and hiding images and such.  Please refer to this stackoverflow question for your answer:

[jQuery doesn't rotate images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897255/jquery-doesnt-rotate-images/15918163#15918163)