# jQuery doesn't rotate images

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm trying to use datalist to fetch image fro list >>> and jQuery to rotate this image but the jQuery doesn't rotate the images .... any one could tell me what's the wrong on my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var activeNewItem = 0;
        $(function () {
            var totalItems = $("#MyRotator LI").length;
            $("#MyRotator LI").hide();
            $("#MyRotator LI::nth-child(" + ((activeNewItem++ % totalItems) + 1) + ")").show();
            setTimeout('RotateWhatsNew()', 5000); //30000
        });       
</script>
<asp:DataList id="rotator"  bordercolor="Black" cellpadding="2" 
    headerstyle-backcolor="DarkBlue" 
    headerstyle-forecolor="Yellow" repeatcolumns="1"    
    runat="server" Height="179px" Width="168px">  
<HeaderStyle BackColor="DarkBlue" ForeColor="Yellow"></HeaderStyle>
<ItemTemplate>
<div id="MyRotator">
        <ul type="none">
<li style='padding: 3px; list-style: none; width: 200px; word-wrap: break-word; display: none'>

                    <img  Id="Image"   height='90%' width='90%' src='<%=siteurl%>/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ThumbnailOnForm")%>'/> 
             </li>
</ul>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Can we have a look at the `RotateWhatsNew()` function? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: shouldn't it be `setTimeout(RotateWhatsNew, 5000);` ? You passing a string instead of the function.

Comment: where is the RotateWhatsNew() function??

Comment: Whate should it be ?? I'm using this jquery script from the internet and I need to know how to use it ???

Comment: Shouldn't it be "LI:nth-child"? I've never used a double colon before.  Are you sure the item is visible that you're trying to rotate?

Comment: honestly, the simplest solution is my code below.  if you want to see the working example then go to www.kitchenbathspecialties.com and you will see it on the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery code to fade images in throughout a sequence
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#BannerSlideshow').innerfade({
        speed: 2500,
        timeout: 7000,
        type: 'sequence',
        containerheight: '300px'
    });

Example of the list of images
<ul id="BannerSlideshow" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li><img src="SiteImages/HeaderBackgrounds/HeaderBackground1.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="SiteImages/HeaderBackgrounds/HeaderBackground2.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="SiteImages/HeaderBackgrounds/HeaderBackground3.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="SiteImages/HeaderBackgrounds/HeaderBackground4.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="SiteImages/HeaderBackgrounds/HeaderBackground5.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="SiteImages/HeaderBackgrounds/HeaderBackground6.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to rotate the div for specific angle means try this css

```
-moz-transform: rotate(344deg);
-o-transform: rotate(344deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand',
M11=0.9396926207859084, M12=0.3420201433256687, M21=-0.3420201433256687,
M22=0.9396926207859084); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', 
M11=0.9396926207859084, M12=0.3420201433256687, M21=-0.3420201433256687, 
M22=0.9396926207859084)"; /* IE8 */
writing-mode: lr-tb;">
```

Answer (score 0):

After Googling for this "RotateWhatsNew" function, the results lead me to think you don't want to physically spin the image but simply hide the list items and only show the new ones.

I think the code should look more like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var activeNewItem = 0,
        waitTime = 5000;

    function RotateWhatsNew() {
        var totalItems = $("#MyRotator li").length;
        $("#MyRotator li").hide();
        $("#MyRotator li:nth-child(" + ((activeNewItem++ % totalItems) + 1) + ")").show();
        setTimeout(RotateWhatsNew, waitTime);
    };  

    $(function() {
      setTimeout(RotateWhatsNew, waitTime);
    });     
</script>
```

Does that help? I may have misunderstood you. I don't see this working out unless the list gets new items appended to it every 5 seconds.

Comment: I have list which contain images ..I just want every after 5 second another image appear and so on like the idea of ads ?

Comment: Do you already have all of the images loaded into the page or are you adding new images via AJAX?

If the <li> tags are already there when the page loads, the script I posted should probably work. You will need to reset the "activeNewItem" to zero when you reach the end of the list though